# Record my iPad screen on MacBook

Tags: ios, ipad, airplay

I have an iPad 1, and MacBook with Snow Leopard 10.6.8. I want to record my iPad screen to MacBook and share the video file.

I thought I can use AirServer and downloaded it. I mirrored my iPad with AirServer. I am able to see the iPad screen through AirServer on MacBook, but I'm not seeing any option to record my iPad screen.

Could someone advise what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There are several 3rd party AirPlay receivers which could run on Mac OS X and receive/record screen mirroring from an iDevice.

You have to download and install one of these applications. Try [LonelyScreen](http://lonelyscreen.soft32.com/mac/) (free) or [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) ($15).

Another way is by using QuickTime. QuickTime on OS X 10.10+ can record iDevice screens, but you must connect your iDevice to Mac, while the AirPlay receiver method can work with Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

AirServer 5 lets you record the mirrored screen. Make sure you are updated to AirServer 5 or later or the option will not be available.

Comment: Hi, I have installed AirServer Version 5.0.4.0. but i didn't see any option to record.

Comment: in order to use the record functionality you need to have OS 10.7, which is a free upgrade from 10.6 http://support.airserver.com/